# VB.NET: How to autopopulate desired data from Datagrid view ComboBoxColumn to another ComboBoxColumn

Tags: vb.net

I don't have codes to show because I created it from scratch and I don't know how to start it. Instead, I will show some image of my desired UI.

I have 2 Columns ("Types of Downtime","Description") in my DataGrid.

I added in Item Collection with ("Manpower", "Machine").

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwn73.jpg]

Here's my expected result.

If I click "Machine" the second column will populate "Motor" and "Computer"

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqn5D.png]

else If I click "Manpower" it will populate "Dela Cruz" and "Dela Torre".

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLkJn.png]

Hope you can help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: What is the final destination of your data? Do you need to store it in a Database? Is it normalized, so the underlying value of each column is numeric and you have a *table of tables* to match the normalized data? Or are you planning to serialize it, so you'll, possibly, just use strings instead?

Comment: No, I dont need to store it in database. I just want to know how to show it in UI.

Comment: The logic is If I click "Machine" the second column will populate "Motor" and "Computer". If I click "Manpower" it will display "Dela Cruz" and "Dela Torre". I really need your help Sir. Thanks.

Comment: I see. So, you could use a `List(Of String)` to populate the first ComboBoxColumn (e.g., `DirectCast(DataGridView1.Columns(0), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = [YourListOfString])`. Use a `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))` as the selector for the second Column. The dictionary Keys are the same values contained in the first List. In the `CellValueChanged` event, use the value of Cell `(0, e.RowIndex)` as the Key to extract the corresponding `List(Of String)` from the Dictionary and use it as the DataSource of the Cell at index `(1, e.RowIndex)` (it's a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`).

Comment: I wish you could help me to construct the syntax. Thanks.